# HTACCESS Rewrite Order

Tags: .htaccess

The line with rewriting index.php and the other three lines work perfectly, but not when put together, I've tried all possibilities with position of the lines, and to be honest pretty exhausted.

My code below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(admin|admin/.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(l|l/.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(includes|includes/.*)$
```

Can anyone help me in this quick question?

The script runs in: http://domain.com/folder/

The .htaccess is also placed in that folder.

The problem is that it rewrites also files in the admin,l and includes folder

Answer (score 1):

I think what is happening here is the first RewriteRule (.*) index.php is set to rewrite everything regardless of if they match the other regex for the 3 RewriteCond's I think maybe moving it to the bottom and reformulating the rule to be more specific to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

There are **few problems** in your Rewrite code:

1. RewriteCond should come before RewriteRule
2. Multiple RewriteCond can be combined into 1
3. You must use L flag to mark last rule

Replace your code with this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(admin|l|includes)(/.*|)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```